# Azure Function stuck, no high CPU

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-functions

Our Azure Function is getting stuck. When we restart, it again starts working as normal. There is no high CPU traced. We checked the following:

1. CPU Utilization - normal - floating between 40-100%
2. Logs before it got stuck - No helpful traces found.
3. Live metrics - Not loading live metrics data
4. Tried manually triggering Azufre function - But getting the error as: The function runtime is unable to start. As per this error, this is a version specific issue. which is well addressed, the function was in running function.
5. We do have one ping request implement - getting 503 error when calling from Postman.
6. Checked function settings - Always On is enabled. runtime version is 1, as we deployed .Net Framework code.

Can you please guide us on finding root cause and permanent fix.

Comment: if you're deploying aspnet core, the runtime should be version ~2

Comment: No, I deployed the code written in .net framework